# Columns to Rows with unknown number of columns (SQL Server & SMSS 18)

Tags: sql, sql-server, function

Let's say I have some table `Table1`:

| Column1 | Column2 | Column3 | Column4 | ... | ... |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| values | values | values | values | ... | ... |

Is there a way to insert the column names into a temporary table

#Temp:

| ColumnNames |
| --- |
| Column1 |
| Column2 |
| Column3 |
| Column4 |

I want a generic function or method to do this for a variable number of columns (I want to apply this method to multiple tables with a different number of columns).

I have looked at forums describing pivot and unpivot, but they either hardcode their column names or are only used for a specified number of columns. I am very new to SQL.

Comment: https://dataedo.com/kb/query/sql-server/list-table-columns-in-database

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).
All within the question as text, no images.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check it out.

The `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS` view has many other useful columns.

[INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertutorial/183/information-schema-columns/)

**SQL**

```
-- DDL and sample data population, start
USE tempdb;
GO

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS dbo.tbl;

CREATE TABLE tbl  (ID INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY, city VARCHAR(20), State CHAR(2), Population INT, InsertedOn DATETIMEOFFSET(3) DEFAULT SYSDATETIMEOFFSET());
INSERT tbl (city, State, Population, InsertedOn) VALUES
('Miami', 'FL', 350000, Default),
('Orlando', 'FL', 300000, Default),
('Dallas', 'TX', 5000000, Default);
-- DDL and sample data population, end

DECLARE @tbl_catalog sysname = 'tempdb'
    , @tbl_name sysname = 'tbl'
    , @schema_name sysname = 'dbo';

SELECT COLUMN_NAME
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_CATALOG = @tbl_catalog
    AND TABLE_SCHEMA = @schema_name
    AND TABLE_NAME = @tbl_name;
```

**Output**

| COLUMN_NAME |
| --- |
| ID |
| city |
| State |
| Population |
| InsertedOn |

Answer (score 1):

Not intended as an answer Yitzhak Khabinsky's solution is spot on +1.

There are other options, this one supports Tables, Views, ad-hoc queries and even Stored Procedures

**Example**

```
Select ColumnName = [name]   -- Try Select * to see all the columns
 From sys.dm_exec_describe_first_result_set('Select * From YourTable',null,null ) A

Select ColumnName = [name]   -- Try Select * to see all the columns
 From sys.dm_exec_describe_first_result_set('Exec [dbo].[prc-MySP]',null,null ) A
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your purpose correctly, you want to store the column names of your table in another table.
You can do this using this code snippet

```
INSERT INTO fields(field)
 select Col_Name
 from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
 where table_name = 'tbl1';
```